# Getting an if-statement to also check for a defined macro

Tags: c++, if-statement, c-preprocessor, code-readability

I have an `if-else` where the `if` should check a flag and whether a macro is defined. I've come up with two solutions but am unsure on which of them to use.

- Will there be a difference in execution time (or will compiler optimization eliminate this)?
- Can the first solution cause bugs with the `else` when the flag isn't defined (i.e. due to lines written above or below the example code)?

Additionally:

- Are there any commonly followed best practices that could apply to this situation?

---

**1**

```
#ifdef FLAG_A
    if(flagB)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
#endif
    {
        ...
    }
```

**2**

```
#ifdef FLAG_A
    bool flagA = true;
#else
    bool flagA = false;
#endif

    if(flagA && flagB)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: One problem with **1** is what happens if you need an `else if()` and/or an additional `#ifdef FLAG_B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the flagA variable is within a local scope (and remains unmodified within that scope), then the two will compile to be exactly the same *(for most compilers, in non-debug build)*. If however flagA is a global, you'd need to declare it as 'constexpr' *(which is probably a good idea in the other case!)*.

Proof: https://godbolt.org/z/r9nra5

In terms of best practices, I'm sure everyone will chip in with their own preference, but I prefer version 1. The only reason is that it's immediately clear that the code within the #ifdef / #endif block is conditionally compiled. It might not be immediately apparent when looking at case 2.